# How to make multiple images in a single row have same height an correct aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

The following is the screenshots.

The left iPhone, where there are 3 images in a single row, are having same height and correct aspect ratio. It is implemented using `UIKit`.

The right iPhone, where there are 3 images in a single row, are having different height and correct aspect ratio. It is implemented using `SwiftUI`.

[image]

I want to use `SwiftUI`, to achieve

1. All 3 images are having same height.
2. All 3 images are having correct aspect ratio.

In `UIKit`, this is how I achieve so

### Step 1: Use a horizontal stack view

```
let horizontalStackView = UIStackView()

horizontalStackView.axis = .horizontal
horizontalStackView.distribution = .fill
horizontalStackView.alignment = .fill
horizontalStackView.spacing = spacing
```

### Step 2: Assign correct constraint to every UIImageView based on original image dimension

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let multiplier = CGFloat((Double)(attachment.height) / (Double)(attachment.width))
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(
    equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor,
    multiplier: multiplier).isActive = true
```

---

However, I am not sure how I can implement similar idea in `SwiftUI`. So far, this is how I achieve imperfect outcome at the right iPhone screenshot. They are having correct aspect ratio. But they are not having same height.

### SwiftUI, incorrect outcome

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                HStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Image("0").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    Image("3").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    
                    Image("2").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }
                Text("Hello, world!")
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have idea, how I can achieve the same outcome in `SwiftUI`, as I did in `UIKit`? Thanks.

Comment: Granted, I've done very little with `SwiftUI`, but one of the things I *don't* like about it is that is seems very difficult to manipulate layouts beyond the "templated" arrangements. One option would be to use a UIKit `UIStackView` as a `UIViewRepresentable` (or a custom `UIView` with sizing constraints applied).

Answer (score 0):

Call `frame(minWidth:idealWidth:maxWidth:minHeight:idealHeight:maxHeight:alignment:)`  and specify `maxHeight`. This ways all images will have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

define aspect ratio same for all images, like this:

```
 HStack(spacing: 2) {
                        
                        Image("0").resizable().aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), contentMode: .fit)
                        
                        Image("1").resizable().aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 3, height: 3),contentMode: .fit)
                        
                        Image("2").resizable().aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 3, height: 3),contentMode: .fit)
                    }
```

you will get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This seems to match what you did on UIKit with similar results. That is, using .fill on the images, restricting the horizontal stack to a fixed size and then calculating the HStack's height based on the device's width multiplied by the aspect ratio of the desired HStack.

This is the original code with changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                HStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Image("0").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    Image("3").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    Image("2").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * (2.1 / 7))
                
                Text("Hello, world!").padding(.leading)
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

The result for an iphone and an ipad:

[image]
[image]

The .aspectRatio doesn't appear to work on an HStack so I used frame() instead. The magic number is a guestimate using the image of your desired layout (height / width). To match the original image, .padding(.leading) was also added.